# Linear Algebra - Understanding how to find eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&0\\1&3&1\end{bmatrix}$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

I think I got a pretty steady ground on how I approached this, I just have some difficulty getting the right answer.

What I have done so far:

$P(\lambda) = det(A - \lambda I)$

$det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&2&1\\0&1-\lambda&0\\1&3&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix} = 0$

$=(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)^2 - 2(0) + 1(1-\lambda) = 0$

$= (1- \lambda) ^3 +(1-\lambda) = 0$

But I'm not getting the right eigenvalues. The above answer gives me the eigenvalue: 1 only.

but the right answer is: 2, 1, 0.

Comment: Check the second term in the equation you obtained after evaluating the determinant: $\begin{vmatrix} 0&0\\1&1-\lambda \end{vmatrix}\not = 1-\lambda$ .

Comment: Or divide the equation by $\lambda-1$ to find the other solutions by solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: Just a hint, look at the first and second columns.

Comment: @FH93 whoops, yeah i changed it but i still am only getting 1 as the answer

Comment: @FH93 third determinant wrong, should get $\lambda-1$ not $1-\lambda$

Comment: As @gt6989b explains, the third term is also incorrect! (only out by a minus sign) Factoring out the $1-\lambda$ and noting that $ab=0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$ should yield the other solutions. Deal with the quadratic term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multiplication is wrong...since the middle row has two zeros, you only have to evaluate using the middle cofactor...
$$\det{(A)}=(1-\lambda)((1-\lambda)^2-1)=(1-\lambda)(1-2\lambda+\lambda^2-1)=(1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-2\lambda)$$
$$=\lambda(1-\lambda)(\lambda-2)$$

Answer (score 1):

You did the determinant wrong, the second term is incorrect, as @FH93 hinted.

Another way is to expand where there are most zeros, saves you work. Let's go by 2nd row:
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&2&1\\0&1-\lambda&0\\1&3&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
 = -(1-\lambda)\left[(1-\lambda)^2-1\right] = 0
$$
which you can take from here...

Comment: Or the second row ^_^

Comment: @hjpotter92 fixed thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've made a little error in calculating your $ \det $ value.

$$ det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&2&1\\0&1-\lambda&0\\1&3&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

will expand to give you:

$$ =(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)^2 - 2(0) + 1 (\color{red}{-1 \times (1 - \lambda)}) = 0 $$

which on further calculations give:

$$ (1 - \lambda)^3 - (1 - \lambda) = (1 - \lambda)((1 - \lambda)^2 - 1) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

You could expand your equation for the determinant about the second row. This gives
\begin{align*}
\det(A-\lambda\cdot I)
&=
\det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&2&1\\0&1-\lambda&0\\1&3&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
(1-\lambda)\cdot\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda & 1 \\
1 & 1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=(1-\lambda)\cdot\left((1-\lambda)^2-1\right) \\
&= (1-\lambda)\cdot((1-\lambda)+1)\cdot((1-\lambda)-1) \\
&= (1-\lambda)\cdot(2-\lambda)\cdot(-\lambda)
\end{align*}
where we utilize the equation $a^2-b^2=(a+b)\cdot(a-b)$ for $a=(1-\lambda)$ and $b=1$. Hence the eigenvalues are $\lambda=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

A trial & error approach:

Note that $A(e_1+e_2) = 2(e_1+e_2)$, and $A(e_1-e_2) = 0$. Note also that $A A^T \neq A^T A$, hence $A$ not normal and cannot be orthogonally diagonalized (so I can just look for a vector normal to the other two).

Try using the basis (or rather the inverse) $P= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, to get $P^{-1} A P = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & {5 \over 2} \\
0 & 0 & -{1 \over 2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, from which we can read off the eigenvalues.

(Note that even though I did above, we do not need to explicitly compute the inverse, we need only solve $Pv_3 = A P e_3 = A e_2$ for the last row of $v_3$.)